# Session hijacking prevention...how far will my script get me? additional prevention procedures?

Tags: php, session, session-hijacking

When the user logs in the current session vairables are set

```
$_SESSION['user']['timeout'] = time();
$_SESSION['user']['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$_SESSION['user']['agent'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

In my common.php page (required on ALL php pages) i have used the below script, which resets a 15 minute timer each time the user is active furhtermore checks the IP address  and checks the user_agent, if they do not match that as of when they first logged in/when the session was first set, the session is unset furthermore with inactivity of up to 15 minutes the session is also unset.

... is what i have done a good method for preventing session hijacking furthermore is it secure and or is it enough? If not what more can be done?

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])){  
    if ($_SESSION['user']['timeout'] + 15 * 60 < time()) {
        unset($_SESSION['user']); 
        } else {
        $_SESSION['user']['timeout'] = time();
        if($_SESSION['user']['ip'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']){
            unset($_SESSION['user']); 
        }
        if($_SESSION['user']['agent'] != $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']){
            unset($_SESSION['user']); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unless you are a bank don't over extend your self

Comment: :) ... I understand you, but you may have heard the saying "you can never be too safe", If i am taking that too far please explain how.. please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the limitation of 15 miniatures you ensure that if the session hijacked, attacker can not use it for a long time, while the user leaved his/her machine or turned it off ( and has not logged off ). But what about the time that user is working and attacker has hijacked the session. Checking ip address is a good idea but there is a small limitation with it. while user doesn't have static ip address and he/she has been disconnected from the network and reconnected. A new ip address will be assigned to it. And this situation forces his session to be expired, while he is a valid user. Also this trick doesn't do anything for attackers that are in the same private LAN with valid user and they both are behind a gateway with a public ip address. because they both have same ip address in your server ( ip address of NAT or gateway ).
In my opinion what you have done is good. But it is better to make the website secure against XSS and CSRF attacks. Preventing javascript injection in client. And if it is so important to prevent any such attacks, also using ssl to be secure againt network sniffers.

Comment: sorry I am pretty new with php, as I have seen all over the net "DO NOT MAKE YOUR OWN LOGIN SYSTEM" the one thing i now want to do is make my own login system :P , what i am doing however before diving into the mainframe of the login system is learning all the hacking prevention techniques, yet my mind is boggled with all these random acronyms of types of hacks/dangers, (I have my head arround XSS and sql injection), can you please tell me what else i should look out for and try prevent as well if you know any, any good books/reads on this subject

Comment: Sorry for delay, I see your comment just now. As you mentioned, xss and sql injection, are points that we should consider. Also other attacks like csrf and some other that are in the top 10 list of owasp, should be considered too. Altough some of them may be less important while we are only talking about a login page. I think you should also prevent reusing of session key.